# Android Layout spacing changed in Nougat 7.0 API 24 and 7.1 API 25

Tags: android, api, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a fragment that contains another fragment at the top, and then a horizontal LinearLayout that has two columns, total weightSum=3.  The left columns is a vertical RelativeLayout (weight 1) with a TextView and a ListView.  The right is a vertical LinearLayout (weight 2) with a TextView and a GridView and a Button. The spacing changed dramatically in Nougat.  Both in the Studio emulators as well as my own Samsung S7 Edge.  Also, the Emulators report different screen layouts.  For the Nexus 6P (1440 x 2560), API 23 reports LARGE, where API 25 reports NORMAL.  My Samsung s7 Edge (1440 x 2560 as well) also reports NORMAL and is running 7.0 (API 24).

In API 24 and up, the right layout is being squeezed really tightly against the right edge, as if weights were being ignored.

API 23 works fine.  I used the same emulator type, 6P and just different APIs.

Here is what API 23 looks like:
[image]

And here is what API 25 looks like:

[image]

And here is my Fragment:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/fragment_course"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.hubbardsoftware.racetac.CourseActivityFragment"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_course">

<fragment
    android:name="com.hubbardsoftware.racetac.TimerFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_timer" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/course_part"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/course_course_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/title_course"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_course_title"
            android:textColor="#ff000000"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview_course"
            android:layout_below="@id/course_course_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/course_part"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/course_part"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/course_marks_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/title_marks"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_course_title"
            android:textColor="#ff000000"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridview_course"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_clear_course"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_rounded"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/clearCourseButton"
            android:text="@string/clear_all"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_course_clear"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/course_length"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Length"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_course_length"
            android:textColor="#ff000000"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Any thoughts as to why the changes ?  Seems like it may be related to the following being true in API 24 and 25 for devices of this size:

```
((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL)
```

Whereas it was equal to Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE in API 23.

Comment: Additional Info:  If I change the RelativeLayout width to 0dp (from 200dp) it works fine on API 24 & 25.  However, on API 23 it now squeezes the right column, although not as badly as above.  I may need to add Java code to detect the rev and change that value manually before displaying it.

Comment: I found a workaround.  See my 'answer', although I'd still like to know if anyone knows of a 'clean' way to do this in the XML.

Answer (score 0):

This Java code workaround resolved the issue, although I'd still like a proper XML solution if anyone knows one.  I left the XML above as is, with the width of the RelativeLayout at 200dp.  I then did the following in my fragment onCreateView method:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    {
        RelativeLayout coursePart = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.course_part);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = coursePart.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = 0;
    }
```

Both older and newer APIs display the same with this code.